# How to send an event from two different view branches in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm building a SwiftUI app for macOS, then I came with the following challenge.

Given a view hierarchy like:

[image: Example View Hierarchy]

Which basically shows a collection of elements in `ElementListView`. Then the `FiltersView` is used to search new elements to possibly add to the element list, the results of that search are shown in rows like `FilterRow`.

When a user clicks on `FilterRow`, that means I want to add a new element to the `ElementListView`, but I am not sure of **How to propagate events between the two branches of the view hierarchy in SwiftUI?**

If I were to implement this in pure AppKit, I would probably use the *responder chain*, but I guess it's not the SwiftUI way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a shared ObservableObject for filters and list views. As soon as ObservableObject changes SwiftUI updates views connected to it.

Comment: Yeah, it make sense... this is the kind of mind-shift we need with swiftUI